# Erro: Acesso ao arquivo bin\Debug\

Tags: c#

Estou vendo algumas vídeo aulas no Youtube sobre C# porém há uma em questão que não consigo resolver a principio.

O código do C# que estou usando é exatamente este abaixo:

```
using System;

namespace IniciandoProjeto
  {
     class Principal
     {
        static void Main(string[] args)

           {
               Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
               Console.ReadKey();
           }
      }
  }
```

Estou usando o `CTRL+F5` para ir vendo o que ocorro na tela, porém não executa. E se utilizo somente o `F5` fica a tela preta, só.

O erros que me aparecem são esses:

```
Warning 10  Could not copy "obj\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe" to "bin\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe". Beginning retry 10 in 1000ms. The process  cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe' because it is being used by another process.    AprendendoVideoAula1

   Error    11  Could not copy "obj\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe" to "bin\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    AprendendoVideoAula1

   Error    12  Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe" to "bin\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\AprendendoVideoAula1.exe' because it is being used by another process.  AprendendoVideoAula1
```

Comment: Você provavelmente tem uma instância do seu executável rodando, e com isso o SO não deixa o compilador sobrescrever o arquivo. Feche todas as instâncias do seu programa, e tente novamente.

Comment: Está executando o arquivo por fora do Visual Studio... quando tenta executar pelo VS, dá o erro indicando o caminho. Veja, conforme o @carlosfigueira comentou, se não tem instâncias o mesmo executável rodando; se houver ao menos uma, e tentar executar no VS não vai funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente há um processo já rodando do Exe que fica dentro do bin. Ai o compilador tenta reescrever e não consegue.

Já ocorreu comigo muitas vezes então é só fazer os passos abaixo que deve funcionar.

> **Solução:** Aperte CTRL + SHIFT + ESC, vai nos processos encontra o processo **AprendendoVideoAula1.exe** no seu caso, finalize ele e tente novamente.

Comment: Cara, há algo errado com meu código? Pois algumas vezes executa, porém a tela permanece preta. E, realmente acontece isso que me disse, aperto `F5` o programa roda e fecha dai quando vou no `CTRL+F5`, olhei no gerenciador de tarefas e o processo já estava executado, porém se tento finalizar fecha todo o VisualStudio

Comment: Então cara eu não manjo muito de C#, para te responder isso. Mas o problema que dá é isso do processo estar iniciado. Oque vc pode tentar fazer é dar um finish() ou um Close() se eu não me engano no final do código em baixo do console.writeline assim o processo não vai ficar preso.

Comment: Tranquilo achei um problema no código, já até editei na pergunta. Porém sua resposta foi útil sim. Nem estava pensando em verificar os processos. Valeu

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentei resolver esse problemas de várias maneiras, e comigo só funcionou depois que eu criei uma pasta dentro do diretório e copiei os arquivos da pasta antiga para essa nova. Só assim meu VS passou a compilar o código e não dar o erro MSB3027.